# Avoid HDFS file access without password

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I created a HDFS user `externUser`, who own the folder `/user/externUser` in the HDFS. the permissions are set to `drwx------`, see screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using HDP 2.4.2 with Ambari 2.2.2

Now I've written a Java application, which opens and reads a csv file in this user folder, using the following code:

```
System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "externUser");
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Path path = new Path(hdfs://namenode_url:8020/user/externUser/test.csv);
FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
FSDataInputStream input = fs.open(path);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
String headerRow = br.readLine();
String[] headers = headerRow.split(";");
br.close();
```

I'm running the Java application from a remote host. Surprisingly I can access the file with this code snippet, **WITHOUT specifying the user's password!** Can someone explain this behavior and how to make the files more secure?

An access via the Ambari HDFS view (screenshot above) is not possible without being logged in as the "correct" user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed an insecure cluster. The default authentication mode is SIMPLE. See [core-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml). In this mode, every user can pretend to be another user as he/she want. In your code, your are predending to be 'externUser'.

You should setup secure mode. The only [secure mode](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html#Hadoop_in_Secure_Mode) hadoop supported is Kerberos. I'm not familar with Ambari, But there's lots of documention about hot to enable Kerberos in Ambari.

More information:
[Setting Up Kerberos for Use with Ambari](https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.5/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/ambari-kerb.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look for this!